# How can I pass a variable to a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, variables, modal-dialog

I use [this Bootstrap table](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#column-events-table), and when I click on edit, I want to pass a variable to my modal, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

you can see the jsFiddle examples here: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/blob/master/docs/jsfiddle-examples.md.